# Mocking a route with arguments in Flutter - Dart

Tags: unit-testing, dart, flutter

I have a widget defined as follows:

```
import ...;
...

class TechnicalError extends StatelessWidget {
    ...

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        TechnicalErrorPayload payload = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

        return Scaffold(
            body: Column(...)
        );
    }
}
```

I also have defined a named route for that widget:

```
import ...;
const String TECHNICAL_DIFFICULTIES = '/technical-difficulties';
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    MyApp() {
        ...
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return MaterialApp(
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
            ...
            TECHNICAL_DIFFICULTIES: (BuildContext context) => TechnicalError()
        }

        ...
        );
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to push that route, I would do as follows:

```
var techErrPayload = TechnicalErrorPayload(...);
await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TECHNICAL_DIFFICULTIES, arguments: techErrPayload);
```

Everything working as expected. The problem comes when I want to test the TechnicalError widget... How to pass a TechnicalErrorPayload to that widget? It is not part of the constructor. It is being taken by the properties of the ModalRoute.

This won't work:

```
testWidgets('Me testing', (WidgetTester tester) async {
MaterialPageRoute test = MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => TechnicalError(),

  settings: RouteSettings(
    name: 'Blah',
    arguments: TechnicalErrorPayload(friendlyErrorMessage: 'Hey Joe')
  )
);

//await tester.pumpWidget(WidgetWrapper.fromRouteWithNavigatorObservers(test, [navigatorobserverMock]));

await tester.pumpWidget(
  MaterialApp(
    navigatorObservers: [navigatorobserverMock],
    routes: {
      '/': (BuildContext context) => test.builder(context)
    },

  )
);
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
});
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

To test a route that uses route arguments I wrapped my screen widget a in a
MaterialPageRoute. Then in the route settings I was able to pass any argument the route needed.

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MaterialApp(
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: RouteSettings(arguments: // Your Argument here),
          builder: (context) {
            return TheScreen();
          },
        );
      },
  )
);
```